# RegEx XSD not matching timestamp value

Tags: regex, xsd-validation

I'm using following pattern in xsd

```
(^$)|(^([1-2]\d{3}-([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0]?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))[ |T]?((([0-1]?\d)|(2[0-3])):[0-5]\d)?(:[0-5]\d)?(\.\d{1,3})?$)
```

While testing, it is failing for value - '2013-01-01T23:59:46'

Could anyone please let me know what's wrong with the regex?

Comment: Should match, according to <http://regexr.com?376j2> are you sure it isn't matching and that it's not another problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `^` and `$` to indicate anchors at the beginning and end of the string being matched.  But XSD patterns are always anchored, and the characters `^` and `$` just denote literal caret and dollar-sign respectively.  Drop them and try again.